# Error with Jekyll: "Liquid Exception: wrong number of arguments (3 for 1..2)…"

Tags: rubygems, rake, bundle, jekyll, liquid

After launching `bundle update` in my Jekyll project, I have this error when I try to build the site with Rake:

```
Configuration file: ./_config.yml
  Liquid Exception: wrong number of arguments (3 for 1..2) in _includes/head.html, included in _layouts/default.html
rake aborted!
Jekyll::Tags::IncludeTagError: wrong number of arguments (3 for 1..2)
/usr/local/lib/ruby/gems/2.2.0/gems/jekyll-2.5.3/lib/jekyll/tags/include.rb:124:in `rescue in render'
/usr/local/lib/ruby/gems/2.2.0/gems/jekyll-2.5.3/lib/jekyll/tags/include.rb:116:in `render'
/usr/local/lib/ruby/gems/2.2.0/gems/liquid-2.6.3/lib/liquid/block.rb:109:in `block in render_all'
/usr/local/lib/ruby/gems/2.2.0/gems/liquid-2.6.3/lib/liquid/block.rb:96:in `each'
/usr/local/lib/ruby/gems/2.2.0/gems/liquid-2.6.3/lib/liquid/block.rb:96:in `render_all'
/usr/local/lib/ruby/gems/2.2.0/gems/liquid-2.6.3/lib/liquid/block.rb:82:in `render'
/usr/local/lib/ruby/gems/2.2.0/gems/liquid-2.6.3/lib/liquid/template.rb:128:in `render'
/usr/local/lib/ruby/gems/2.2.0/gems/liquid-2.6.3/lib/liquid/template.rb:138:in `render!'
/usr/local/lib/ruby/gems/2.2.0/gems/jekyll-2.5.3/lib/jekyll/convertible.rb:106:in `render_liquid'
/usr/local/lib/ruby/gems/2.2.0/gems/jekyll-2.5.3/lib/jekyll/convertible.rb:205:in `render_all_layouts'
/usr/local/lib/ruby/gems/2.2.0/gems/jekyll-2.5.3/lib/jekyll/convertible.rb:239:in `do_layout'
/usr/local/lib/ruby/gems/2.2.0/gems/jekyll-archives-2.0.0/lib/jekyll-archives/archive.rb:104:in `render'
/usr/local/lib/ruby/gems/2.2.0/gems/jekyll-archives-2.0.0/lib/jekyll-archives.rb:96:in `block in render'
/usr/local/lib/ruby/gems/2.2.0/gems/jekyll-archives-2.0.0/lib/jekyll-archives.rb:95:in `each'
/usr/local/lib/ruby/gems/2.2.0/gems/jekyll-archives-2.0.0/lib/jekyll-archives.rb:95:in `render'
/usr/local/lib/ruby/gems/2.2.0/gems/jekyll-archives-2.0.0/lib/jekyll-archives.rb:40:in `generate'
/usr/local/lib/ruby/gems/2.2.0/gems/jekyll-2.5.3/lib/jekyll/site.rb:280:in `block in generate'
/usr/local/lib/ruby/gems/2.2.0/gems/jekyll-2.5.3/lib/jekyll/site.rb:279:in `each'
/usr/local/lib/ruby/gems/2.2.0/gems/jekyll-2.5.3/lib/jekyll/site.rb:279:in `generate'
/usr/local/lib/ruby/gems/2.2.0/gems/jekyll-2.5.3/lib/jekyll/site.rb:50:in `process'
/Users/nhoizey/Dropbox/Personnel/Devs/nh.com/Rakefile:15:in `block (2 levels) in <top (required)>'
ArgumentError: wrong number of arguments (3 for 1..2)
/usr/local/lib/ruby/gems/2.2.0/gems/autoprefixer-rails-6.0.3/lib/autoprefixer-rails.rb:17:in `install'
/usr/local/lib/ruby/gems/2.2.0/gems/jekyll-assets-0.13.0/lib/jekyll/assets_plugin/environment.rb:71:in `install_autoprefixer!'
/usr/local/lib/ruby/gems/2.2.0/gems/jekyll-assets-0.13.0/lib/jekyll/assets_plugin/environment.rb:37:in `initialize'
/usr/local/lib/ruby/gems/2.2.0/gems/jekyll-assets-0.13.0/lib/jekyll/assets_plugin/patches/site_patch.rb:28:in `new'
/usr/local/lib/ruby/gems/2.2.0/gems/jekyll-assets-0.13.0/lib/jekyll/assets_plugin/patches/site_patch.rb:28:in `assets'
/usr/local/lib/ruby/gems/2.2.0/gems/jekyll-assets-0.13.0/lib/jekyll/assets_plugin/renderer.rb:38:in `render_asset'
/usr/local/lib/ruby/gems/2.2.0/gems/jekyll-assets-0.13.0/lib/jekyll/assets_plugin/tag.rb:11:in `render'
/usr/local/lib/ruby/gems/2.2.0/gems/liquid-2.6.3/lib/liquid/block.rb:109:in `block in render_all'
/usr/local/lib/ruby/gems/2.2.0/gems/liquid-2.6.3/lib/liquid/block.rb:96:in `each'
/usr/local/lib/ruby/gems/2.2.0/gems/liquid-2.6.3/lib/liquid/block.rb:96:in `render_all'
/usr/local/lib/ruby/gems/2.2.0/gems/liquid-2.6.3/lib/liquid/block.rb:82:in `render'
/usr/local/lib/ruby/gems/2.2.0/gems/liquid-2.6.3/lib/liquid/template.rb:128:in `render'
/usr/local/lib/ruby/gems/2.2.0/gems/liquid-2.6.3/lib/liquid/template.rb:138:in `render!'
/usr/local/lib/ruby/gems/2.2.0/gems/jekyll-2.5.3/lib/jekyll/tags/include.rb:121:in `block in render'
/usr/local/lib/ruby/gems/2.2.0/gems/liquid-2.6.3/lib/liquid/context.rb:112:in `stack'
/usr/local/lib/ruby/gems/2.2.0/gems/jekyll-2.5.3/lib/jekyll/tags/include.rb:119:in `render'
/usr/local/lib/ruby/gems/2.2.0/gems/liquid-2.6.3/lib/liquid/block.rb:109:in `block in render_all'
/usr/local/lib/ruby/gems/2.2.0/gems/liquid-2.6.3/lib/liquid/block.rb:96:in `each'
/usr/local/lib/ruby/gems/2.2.0/gems/liquid-2.6.3/lib/liquid/block.rb:96:in `render_all'
/usr/local/lib/ruby/gems/2.2.0/gems/liquid-2.6.3/lib/liquid/block.rb:82:in `render'
/usr/local/lib/ruby/gems/2.2.0/gems/liquid-2.6.3/lib/liquid/template.rb:128:in `render'
/usr/local/lib/ruby/gems/2.2.0/gems/liquid-2.6.3/lib/liquid/template.rb:138:in `render!'
/usr/local/lib/ruby/gems/2.2.0/gems/jekyll-2.5.3/lib/jekyll/convertible.rb:106:in `render_liquid'
/usr/local/lib/ruby/gems/2.2.0/gems/jekyll-2.5.3/lib/jekyll/convertible.rb:205:in `render_all_layouts'
/usr/local/lib/ruby/gems/2.2.0/gems/jekyll-2.5.3/lib/jekyll/convertible.rb:239:in `do_layout'
/usr/local/lib/ruby/gems/2.2.0/gems/jekyll-archives-2.0.0/lib/jekyll-archives/archive.rb:104:in `render'
/usr/local/lib/ruby/gems/2.2.0/gems/jekyll-archives-2.0.0/lib/jekyll-archives.rb:96:in `block in render'
/usr/local/lib/ruby/gems/2.2.0/gems/jekyll-archives-2.0.0/lib/jekyll-archives.rb:95:in `each'
/usr/local/lib/ruby/gems/2.2.0/gems/jekyll-archives-2.0.0/lib/jekyll-archives.rb:95:in `render'
/usr/local/lib/ruby/gems/2.2.0/gems/jekyll-archives-2.0.0/lib/jekyll-archives.rb:40:in `generate'
/usr/local/lib/ruby/gems/2.2.0/gems/jekyll-2.5.3/lib/jekyll/site.rb:280:in `block in generate'
/usr/local/lib/ruby/gems/2.2.0/gems/jekyll-2.5.3/lib/jekyll/site.rb:279:in `each'
/usr/local/lib/ruby/gems/2.2.0/gems/jekyll-2.5.3/lib/jekyll/site.rb:279:in `generate'
/usr/local/lib/ruby/gems/2.2.0/gems/jekyll-2.5.3/lib/jekyll/site.rb:50:in `process'
/Users/nhoizey/Dropbox/Personnel/Devs/nh.com/Rakefile:15:in `block (2 levels) in <top (required)>'
Tasks: TOP => site:index => site:generate
(See full trace by running task with --trace)
```

The commit in my git repository is this one:
https://github.com/nhoizey/nicolas-hoizey.com/commit/92cada8de17a56f98a28be45a2a12c7302dc188a

Any idea which updated gem can cause this?

Comment: It seems it came when upgrading rails-autoprefixer from 5.2.1.2 to 6.0.3: https://github.com/nhoizey/nicolas-hoizey.com/commit/92cada8de17a56f98a28be45a2a12c7302dc188a#diff-e79a60dc6b85309ae70a6ea8261eaf95L14

Comment: 5.2.1.3 works well, but I get the error above when trying 6.0.0

Comment: I opened an issue on autoprefixer-rails github repo: https://github.com/ai/autoprefixer-rails/issues/81